# Proper Handling of hasMany/belongsTo in Ember Data with Rails Persistence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember.js app (1.0.0-rc.3) using Ember Data (Rev 12) to persist to a Rails backend.  On the client side, I have two models that have a one-to-many relationship:

```
App.Child = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr('string')
  parent: DS.belongsTo('App.Parent')

App.Parent = DS.Model.extend(
  name: DS.attr('string')
  children: DS.hasMany('App.Child')
)
```

I have configured my store to expect JSON from Rails that embeds relationships rather than side-loading them:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend(
  revision: 12
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend(serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend(init: ->
    @_super()
    @map "App.Child",
      parents:
        embedded: "always"

  ))
)
```

And then I have a form for creating a new `App.Child` record.  In the childNewController for the new `App.Child` form view, I create a new `App.Child` and a new `App.Parent` as follows:

```
@transaction = @get('store').transaction()
@set('content', @transaction.createRecord(App.Child, {}))
@set('content.parent', @transaction.createRecord(App.Parent, {}))
```

I have textfields bound to the various attributes of both child and parent. When I click the save button on the form, an action in the childNewController commits the changes with `@transaction.commit()`.

THE PROBLEM

When the transaction is committed, Rails receives two JSON POST requests—one to the ParentController with JSON that looks like:

```
{"parent"=>{"name"=>"William"}}
```

...and a second POST to the ChildController with JSON that looks like:

```
{"child"=>{"name"=>"Henry", "parent"=>{"name"=>"William"}}}
```

Now the Rails ChildController and ParentController are both trying to save the new parent.

Ideally, the request to the ParentController would go away, since I don't want it, and it lacks sufficient information to establish a relationship with the child. I would simply ignore the request to ParentController, but Ember Data is expecting a response from the server.

Another option would be to let ParentController save the new parent, and then ChildController could look up the newly-saved parent record and create the linkage to the new child record. The problem is that the sequence of the two requests is unpredictable.

Because of this sequencing issue, I tried putting `Parent.find_or_create_by_name(parent_name)` in both Rails controllers, on the theory that if one controller has already created the new parent, the other would only execute a lookup of that new parent record. However, this resulted in duplicate parent records!

I'm really at a loss to understand why Ember Data insists on pushing duplicate JSON representations of the parent to the backend.  I'm sure it's a simple configuration error on my part.

**Update**

I found an acceptable workaround for now by chaining the commits:

```
newParent = @transaction.createRecord(App.Parent, {name: parentName})
currentChild = @get('content')  # we assigned a new App.Child to the childNewController in the new child route's controller setup
currentStore = @get('store')

newParent.one('didCreate', this, ->
  now = new Date()
  transaction = currentStore.transaction()
  transaction.add currentChild
  transaction.commit()
  transaction = null
)
newParent.get('transaction').commit()
@transaction = null
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I am trying something similar, just the other way around, so I have the parent-model and want the child-model included. I am getting nothing to work so far. And furthermore I am trying your not updated approach and don't even get the parent model to be included in my child model. Did you make any progress here?